# VS2015 error - Process with an Id of -1 is not running

Tags: .net, xunit, visual-studio-2015

I see this this error frequently in VS2015 Community Edition:

```
Process with an Id of -1 is not running.
```

after running test cases using xunit and .NET Core projects with framework net46.

It seems like some processes are not properly terminated when an exception happens during the test.

When it happens I tend to find a process named dotnet that cannot be killed.

The only workaround I have found so far is to restart Visual Studio, which is kind of annoying.

Can anybody suggest how to troubleshoot this? Or perhaps explain why it might happen?

Some more details from my Visual Studio Help:

```
            Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
            Version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3
            Microsoft.NET Framework
            Version 4.6.01038

            Installed Version: Community

            Visual Basic 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA567
            Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

            Visual C# 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA567
            Microsoft Visual C# 2015

            Visual C++ 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA567
            Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

            Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   7.5.00830.1
            Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

            ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1   14.1.20624.0
            ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1

            ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0
            For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

            ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0
            For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

            Azure App Service Tools v2.9   14.0.20316.0
            Azure App Service Tools v2.9

            Azure Data Lake Node   1.0
            This package contains the Data Lake integration nodes for Server Explorer.

            Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.0.6000.0
            Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

            Common Azure Tools   1.8
            Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

            JavaScript Language Service   2.0
            JavaScript Language Service

            JavaScript Project System   2.0
            JavaScript Project System

            JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2016.2    Build 106.0.20160818.163633
            JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate package for Microsoft Visual Studio.For more information about ReSharper Ultimate, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper. Copyright © 2016 JetBrains, Inc.

            Microsoft.NET Core Tools (Preview 2)   14.1.20624.0
            Microsoft.NET Core Tools(Preview 2)

            Microsoft Azure HDInsight HQL Service   2.0.6000.0
            Language service for Hive query

            Microsoft Azure HDInsight Tools for Visual Studio   2.0.6000.0
            An integrated development environment for HDInsight application development.

            Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
            Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

            Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9
            Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - v2.9.40323.3

            NuGet Package Manager   3.5.0
            NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

            PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
            Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

            SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60519.0
            Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

            TestDriven.Net   3
            TestDriven.Net

            ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
            Hosting json editor into a tool window

            TypeScript   1.8.36.0
            TypeScript tools for Visual Studio
```